# Azure Monitor - How to list metric for a resource

Tags: azure

I am trying to list metrics for a resource which is there in Azure like:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/monitor-dotnet-metrics-api/blob/master/Program.cs

Here I am first making the call to get the metric definition for a resource and using the metric definition I am making calls to get the metrics.

The issue with this approach here is
When I will have millions of resources in azure at that time making millions of API calls to get the metric definition will cost a lot.

can anyone help me out here to optimize this solution which works well in larger environment?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by caching the metric definition by Resource Type + SKU Name

More information can be found here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/33240